# What is ideal Breadcrumbs markup receipt for all of Search engines (Google, Yandex, Bing, Yahoo and others)

Tags: html, seo, breadcrumbs, microdata

Does anybody knows some good universal solution for all of significant Searchers?

Ideally, it must be only Microdata decision right in HTML markup of the page.

We made one just accordingly to [Google advices](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb), but may be somebody knows a general decision?

---

For example, we need SEO-breadcrumbs for `home > catalog > category > product`

The GOAL:

Search Engine must correctly understand our site structure by given breadcrumbs nav microdata and **shows in it's search results**.

So, the link

```
https://example.com/catalog/cat_category/123
```

must become seen as

```
Vendor > Catalog > Category > ProductName
```

where, in ideal case, all of "*search-engine-result-breadcrumbs*" are valid clickable links to appropriate site pages.

Comment: There is a W3Schools post — https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_breadcrumbs.asp — about that, in which they use a simple `ul > li > a`. Apparently, the W3C recomends — https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/breadcrumb/index.html — using `nav > ol > li > a`. CSS Tricks — https://css-tricks.com/markup-for-breadcrumbs/ — experimented `nav > p > a`.

Comment: 1) Please include the Microdata you came up with for Google. 2) Did you check the documentation for the rich results from other search engines? 3) Do they conflict with what you have for Google?